# Install RTW88 WiFi driver

Tags: wireless, asus, realtek, realtek-wireless

I have an ASUS X405U with Ubuntu 18.04. I've had problems with the wifi connection since the beginning, and I could solve them until now.

Lately, sometimes the connection is extremely slow, and the wifi keeps randomly failing (it just "disappears") so I have to run `sudo service network-manager restart`, even sometimes it doesn't work and I need to reboot.

I know there is some new Realtek driver, RTW88, which I hope can fix everything. How can I install it?

Let me know if you need any system information. Thanks.

---

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2950]
    Kernel driver in use: r8822be
    Kernel modules: r8822be, wl
```

Output of `nmcli dev wifi list` with wifi working:

```
IN-USE  SSID           MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
*       Familia Munoz  Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  65      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2
```

Output of `nmcli dev wifi list` after wifi crash:

```
IN-USE  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
```

Output of `dmesg | grep -e r88 -e rtl` with wifi working:

```
[   38.974962] r8822be: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   38.988582] r8822be 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   39.016594] r8822be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8822befw.bin
[   39.070299] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   39.071704] r8822be: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   40.205859] r8822be 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

The output after the failure is the same but with the final line

```
[ 5263.365570] r8822be: AP off, try to reconnect now
```

---

New output of `dmesg | grep -e r88 -e rtl` after failure:

```
[   33.869049] r8822be: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   33.882232] r8822be 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   33.917453] r8822be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8822befw.bin
[   33.933010] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   33.933226] r8822be: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   34.105866] r8822be 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 3868.671203] r8822be: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[10093.691441] r8822be: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
```

I believe there is a "switch is on" line for each time I have restarted the network-manager.

Output of `dmesg | grep wlp` (short) after failure in 3573:

```
[   36.613832] r8822be 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   56.161528] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   56.789080] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   56.876570] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   60.536567] wlp3s0: authenticate with 8c:e1:17:89:62:5a
[   60.574341] wlp3s0: send auth to 8c:e1:17:89:62:5a (try 1/3)
[   60.576518] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   60.580053] wlp3s0: associate with 8c:e1:17:89:62:5a (try 1/3)
[   60.583760] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 8c:e1:17:89:62:5a (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[   60.584167] wlp3s0: associated
[   60.635162] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[   60.637428] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 8c:e1:17:89:62:5a
[ 3573.615659] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 8c:e1:17:89:62:5a by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 3578.411916] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[ 3579.008456] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[ 3579.580439] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[ 3579.581045] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
```

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 reached end of life on July 19, 2018. You are no longer receiving crucial security updates. Please install a supported version.

Comment: Okay @chili555 . I upgraded. What can I do now? Thanks.

Comment: Now let's identify your exact device. Open a terminal and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Please edit your question to include the result.

Comment: Done. I added the output.

Comment: Please remove the incorrect Broadcom driver: `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` Next, please edit your question to show: `nmcli dev wifi list`

Comment: Okay, I added the output after doing that.

Comment: Please also add: `dmesg | grep -e r88 -e rtl` Very interesting problem!

Comment: Done. I also added something about the previous output.

Comment: I suspect that "AP off" means that the wireless card is having trouble following the auto settings in the router. Please see my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

I have worked on more than one case where a space in the name of the SSID or router hindered smooth, constant connection. I recommend that you change the name of your SSID to FamiliaMunoz or Familia_Munoz or some such without any space in the name.

After making these changes, reboot the router. Please test and report.

Comment: There is an _Authentication Type_ that is set to **WPA/WPA2-PSK**, the other options are **WPA-PSK**, **WPA2-PSK**, **WPA-EAP**, and **WPA2-EAP**. Which should I choose?

The _WAP Encryption Algorithm_ was **TKIP-AES** and I changed to **AES**.

Comment: Please choose WPA2-PSK and AES. Your wireless should be more stable if it is not constantly trying to adapt to an auto-select, always changing environment.

Comment: Okay, I think I did everything you say, but it happened again. The output of `dmesg | grep -e r88 -e rtl` is now different. I added it in the question.

Comment: Nothing unusual there. Let's see: `dmesg | grep wlp`

Comment: Okay. I added the output from another day, which is shorter. Thanks for any help.